# Como obtener un valor de una columna de grupo en un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

De este dataframe, necesito obtener el primer valor de la columna 'Date' (2020-08-19), pero no sé como hacerlo. Para obtener el resto de valores de las demás columnas, utilizo por ejemplo, df.iloc[0,3], que me da el valor 21.71, pero para la columna Date no sé cómo hacerlo. Alguna sugerencia?

```
             Open   High    Low  Close  Volume Currency
Date                                                   
2020-08-19  21.12  21.71  20.87  21.71  635549      EUR
2020-08-18  21.00  21.67  20.81  21.15  631806      EUR
2020-08-17  21.19  21.39  20.90  21.16  842990      EUR
2020-08-14  21.50  21.50  20.48  21.27  869349      EUR
2020-08-13  21.79  21.99  21.52  21.52  771586      EUR
```

```
valor = df.iloc[0,3] # me da como resultado 21.71  
valor = df.iloc[0,0] # me da como resultado 21.12
```

Comment: Por favor coloca lo que hayas intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método iloc para extraer elementos en base a su ubicación, por ejemplo:

**Código**:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creamos el dataframe con datos de ejemplo:
data = [['2020-10-10', 'Adrian'], ['2020-11-11', 'Antonio']]   

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Birthday', 'Name'])   

# Imprimimos el resultado cogiendo del dataframe el apartado Birthday la primera ubicación:
print(df['Birthday'].iloc[0])
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
2020-10-10
```

Creando un ejemplo en resumen de lo que planteas:

**Código**:

```
import pandas as pd 
  
data = [
['2020-08-19', '21.12', '21.71', '20.87', '21.71', '635549', 'EUR'], 
['2020-08-18', '21.00', '21.67', '20.81', '21.15', '631806', 'EUR']
] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Currency'])
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
2020-08-19
```

**Dónde df equivale a**:

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
         Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume Currency
0  2020-08-19  21.12  21.71  20.87  21.71  635549      EUR
1  2020-08-18  21.00  21.67  20.81  21.15  631806      EUR
```

Tienes más información en el siguiente enlace: [Indexación con iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

**EDITO**:

Entiendo la pregunta. Esto es porque está utilizando un índice. Le voy a colocar como índice la columna 'Date' con el método set_index.

**Código**:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
['2020-08-19', '21.12', '21.71', '20.87', '21.71', '635549', 'EUR'],
['2020-08-18', '21.00', '21.67', '20.81', '21.15', '631806', 'EUR']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Currency'])

df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df)
```

**Resultado**: Vemos que sería similar a tu dataframe:

```
$ ->  python3 dataframe_example.py 
             Open   High    Low  Close  Volume Currency
Date                                                   
2020-08-19  21.12  21.71  20.87  21.71  635549      EUR
2020-08-18  21.00  21.67  20.81  21.15  631806      EUR
```

Podemos acceder al índice con el método índex. Si imprimimos el resultado,
vemos el Index del dataframe:

```
print(df.index)
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
Index(['2020-08-19', '2020-08-18'], dtype='object', name='Date')
```

Ahora podemos acceder a él como una lista. Imprimimos el primer valor:

```
print(df.index[0])
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 dataframe_example.py 
2020-08-19
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, pero creo que no es eso. Si te fijas, el dataframe que genera esta utilidad externa, la columna 'Date' la genera más abajo, por eso creo que puede ser un grupo. 

Si pongo : print(df.iloc[0,0]) el valor que me dá es '21.12' (no '2020-08-19' que es lo que quiero obtener). O sea, que según deduzco, toma como primera columna 'Open'. 

En el ejemplo que pones, df.iloc[0:0] si saldría '2020-08-19' porque la columna 'Date' está a la misma altura que las demás.

Comment: Sí. En tu caso está como un índice la columna 'Date'. He editado la respuesta. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias !! Ahora funciona perfectamente poniendo df.index[0] !